# Storing $scopes in a factory

Tags: angularjs

I'm adding features to a Web application that I did not write myself.  I feel that a swipe feature cannot be added.

I saw somewhere "$scope cannot be accessed in a factory", but I somehow managed to store all scopes created by an ng-repeat in a factory. Since JavaScript passes by value I'm probably not "storing the scope" but still if I set the scopes ng-class within the factory I can clearly see the difference.  I thought it was a good idea since scope traversing is a pain. Did I strike gold or am I wasting speed and space on storing the massive data which is scope?

**HTML**

main.html

```
<div ng-controller="someCtrlWhichWasDeclaredALongTimeAgo">
    .
    .
    . 
    <div class="items-container"
         ui-sortable="sortableOptions"
         ng-model="selectedSession.items">
        <div ng-repeat="item in selectedSession.items"
             ng-controller="itemEditorCtrl"
             ng-class="{'item-last':$last}">
            <div ng-if="item._value !== undefined"
                 class="item inline-comment">
                <span class="handle"></span>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="item._value === undefined"
                 class="item"
                 ng-include="'/views/item-editor.html'"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="stopper"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

item-editor.html

```
<div item-editor
     swipe-function="swipeMe"
     ng-swipe-left="swipeLeft(item)" 
     ng-swipe-right="swipeRight(item)">
     ...
</div>
```

This will render a list with my magic code. If an item in list is clicked it will expand to full screen. You should be able to swipe between the items from there.

I don't think I have to post more than the HTML to explain the problem. I did manage to make the swipe happen with $rootScope.$broadcast but what if I have hundred items in my list? Will it not grow slower with more and more items receiving message and processing them? I'd rather just load all of the scopes into one factory on selection of this session and then get rid of it when a session is deselected. It might need some time to start but it doesn't take 5 minutes to swipe.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you *do* end up injecting the `$scope` it will need to executed inside of a closure because that same service instance can be injected by other controllers running that would then inject a different `$scope` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "$scope cannot be accessed in a factory"

You're *almost* correct.  You can't inject the `$scope` service into another service.  There's nothing stopping you from creating a service that stores data, and putting $scope in as that data.

**THIS IS A BAD IDEA**.  Services are used to share data between components.  `$scope` is used to communicate with the view.  Think of this as bananas and toasters.  Both have purposes, no one will fault you for using one or the other, but using a service to store $scope is like stuffing a banana in a toaster.

Each component using `$scope` should only be concerned with its own scope - and no other (there are very rare exceptions but you shouldn't use them unless you know what you're doing).

Instead, put data in services and then put the service's data onto the scope:

```
.controller('ExampleController', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.names = myService.names;
});
```

Even better, you can look into using [`controllerAs` syntax](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)

Comment: CLEARLY you have never filled a banana with mars chocolate, wrapped it in tinfoil and stuck it in a toaster.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is totally fine. You can pass scope objects around your application at will. Just keep in mind what they represent. The `$scope` object is your interface with the view. Most of the time your services are going to have little to do with the view and should ideally be used to share data between controllers and directives. That said, there are several examples where it makes total sense for a service to indirectly affect a view. For example, we wrote a [spinner service](http://codetunnel.io/how-to-do-loading-spinners-the-angular-way/) that allows spinner directives to register themselves with the service.

The spinner directive injects the `spinnerService` into it, calls the `spinnerService.register` function and passes in its isolate scope so the service can keep track of it and use it to toggle the spinner on and off. Then our devs can inject the service wherever they need it and hide/show loading spinners or groups of spinners when they need to.

What they mean by "$scope cannot be accessed in a factory" is that you cannot *inject* `$scope` inside a factory. `$scope` is tied to a DOM element (the element the controller or isolate directive was invoked on), so injecting a fresh `$scope` into a factory doesn't make much sense and is in fact impossible. You can't do `app.factory('myFactory', function ($scope) { ... });` but you can definitely call your factory/service from a controller or directive and pass the scope object from there into a method you provide on your service.

There is nothing wrong with tracking scopes within services as long as you know what you're doing. People will tell you that you can't pass your scope into a service because it's an anti-pattern, but then they'll suggest putting something like this in your directive/controller and then passing it to the service:

```
var api = {
  hideSpinner: function () {
    $scope.show = false;
  },
  showSpinner: function () {
    $scope.show = true;
  }
};
```

Sure, you're not *directly* passing your `$scope` object to the service, but if the argument is that your scope object could get stuck in memory and never garbage collected, this solution doesn't help either. The API object you build and pass around takes its JavaScript scope chain with it, keeping in memory all the variables within the scope that it was defined, including the `$scope` of your controller/directive. It has to, or else those API methods wouldn't work. Your `$scope` ***is*** a sort of API for that component and it's fine to use it that way.

A better argument for doing something like the above example is that perhaps your `$scope` object contains information or functions that you don't need/want to share with the service. Making a little API object with just the things you want to expose to the service makes perfect sense there. Then your service only has access to the things you want it to have access to and can still affect the controller/directive `$scope`, but only in the ways outlined by the API object you passed in.

Comment: I think the primary argument is that the `$scope` object would have to be placed inside a closure to work accurately. Since services are shared memory, the `$scope` that's injected into a services API would change if it were not executed inside of a closure. This can get quite messy, but I have seen it done and even done it in extreme cases.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "would have to be placed inside a closure to work accurately." Do you have an example of what you're referring to? The spinner solution I linked to is a great example of storing scopes in a service and it has worked flawlessy for quite a while now. I would even argue that the pattern is completely valid and not an anti-pattern at all.

Comment: So I don't have time to build an example right now, but what I mean is since the memory is shared inside the service, it's not safe to store the `$scope` in the service itself. You need to build a [closure for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) so that it can't be changed by other consumers, ensuring you're always executing against the right instance. See, if the controller were to inject a `$scope` and then a directive were to inject an isolate scope and you stored it *in the service* when the controller tried to use it then it would be the wrong scope.

Comment: I don't think we're talking about the same thing. Take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/chevex/ea450b8eecb302705ba6). This service caches all the scope objects for each spinner directive that registers itself with the service. It stores each scope in a `cache` object. Each directive is required to have a unique ID and passes that into the service as well. It never overwrites one scope with another one; is that what you meant? Without an example I'm still not understanding the issue or how it means you shouldn't ever store a scope object in a data structure inside a service.

Comment: So that pattern would absolutely work as it's a pattern used in singleton's all the time. I would recommend however that it be included in your answer. It would have clarified your position. See, building a cache, closure, or injecting a closure all solve the same problem. What **cannot be done** is housing the scope object in the services memory directly as a local variable, and that is the most common mistake, and thus why I warn against it.

Comment: I get that but that doesn't answer his question and thus isn't in my answer. However, if you clicked the link to the article it's right there. He specifically mentions storing the scopes generated by ng-repeats, which means he is almost certainly doing the same thing. He's not encountering the problem you present and I prefer to be succinct and address just the concern he expressed.

Comment: Ok wow, my first stackoverflow question. Imma put a little bit more effort into it so you guys wont #BreakTheInternet.

Comment: @Freysi21: I don't know what that means. There's nothing wrong with a little healthy debate. What you're doing is fine. Just be aware that there are some mistakes you can make when dealing with scopes outside of the context you're used to dealing with them in. If you encounter a hurdle simply ask another question and the smart people that enjoy browsing stack will be happy to set you straight. As it stands, the pattern you describe in your question is valid.

Comment: @AlexFord You guys are fighting about something you really don't have much info on so "Imma put a little bit more effort into it" is me updating the description of the problem. And i completely agree about the debating thing.

Answer (score 1):

Please stay away from storing `$scope` objects in any type of global store. This includes $rootScope and Angular Services.

Since services in Angular are singleton, if any service is tracking `$scope` object (in any service variable) then the `$scope` may never get release, and there are chances of memory leaks.

Also the concept of `scope` is tightly tied to view and should not be used outside that context.

Maybe you can share some code around your implementation so we can suggest better solution.

Comment: I kinda just wanted that answer or "What!? You can do that?! Go right ahead man". Though i preferred the second one this one is good. Thank you :)